# Randomizing value in a drop down picker in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to randomize the value from my drop down picker and at the same time, to pass on to the next screen but I am having trouble on randomizing the value.

Drop Down Picker

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
             {label: 'Fast Food', value: 'Fast Food'},                  
             {label: 'Western', value: 'Western'},
             {label:'Beverage', value:'Berverage'},
             {label:'Chinese', value:'Chinese'},
             {label: 'Korean', value: 'Korean'},
             {label: 'Taiwanese', value: 'Taiwanese'},                  
             {label: 'Malay', value: 'Malay'},
             {label: 'Indonesian', value: 'Indonesian'},
             {label: 'Indian', value: 'Indian'},                  
             {label: 'Vietnamese', value: 'Vietnamese'},
             {label: 'Japanese', value: 'Japanese'},
             {label: 'Italian', value: 'Italian'},
             {label: 'Desserts', value: 'Desserts'},
             {label: 'Others', value: 'Others'},
            ]);
```

Function

```
const setRandomValue = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    setValue([items[randomIndex].label.toLowerCase()]);
    console.log(randomIndex)
    }
```

Button

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={setRandomValue}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Random</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

The error I get is "Cannot find Variable:setRandomValue'' Is there something I need to download?

HomeScreen code (Without the styling)

```
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
             {label: 'Fast Food', value: 'Fast Food'},                  
             {label: 'Western', value: 'Western'},
             {label:'Beverage', value:'Berverage'},
             {label:'Chinese', value:'Chinese'},
             {label: 'Korean', value: 'Korean'},
             {label: 'Taiwanese', value: 'Taiwanese'},                  
             {label: 'Malay', value: 'Malay'},
             {label: 'Indonesian', value: 'Indonesian'},
             {label: 'Indian', value: 'Indian'},                  
             {label: 'Vietnamese', value: 'Vietnamese'},
             {label: 'Japanese', value: 'Japanese'},
             {label: 'Italian', value: 'Italian'},
             {label: 'Desserts', value: 'Desserts'},
             {label: 'Others', value: 'Others'},
            ]);
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut(auth)
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
   const setRandomValue = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    setValue([items[randomIndex].label.toLowerCase()]);
    console.log(randomIndex)
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome {auth.currentUser?.email}</Text>
      <Text></Text>
      <Text>What cusine would you like to eat today?</Text>
      <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
    
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SubScreen1", {paramKey:value})}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Search</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
      //  onPress={setRandomValue}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Random</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleSignOut}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

It has been pointed out to me that I am console logging the index in this case as my console log is for the randomIndex. So I wanted to see if I can get the value that I have defined by throwing it to a variable and console logging that. But the result I get was `undefined`. How do I solve this?

Edited Function

```
const setRandomValue = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    const randomValue = setValue([items[randomIndex].label.toLowerCase()]);
    console.log(randomIndex)
    console.log(randomValue)
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your whole code? seems like your `setRandomValue` function is below your `render` function.

Comment: Hi, I just posted the whole code @PathikGandhi

Comment: As per the code you have posted, I can see your `setRandomValue` function is inside  the `handleSignOut` function move it outside so render can access that,

Comment: Oh wait, I didnt realise that. Thanks ! Now it works it is giving me numeric value whenever i pressed the random button. Is there any way to change it to the value in my drop down picker? This is because I want to pass this value such as 'Japanese' to the next page and then this 'Japanese' is used to search thru firebase database to extract the items I want

Comment: Try to change the code 
setValue([items[randomIndex].value]);

Comment: I tried and it is still giving me numeric value

Comment: I have edited the post with new findings and now I am getting undefined @PathikGandhi